# Find all intergers such that $2n^2+1$ divides $n^3+9n-17$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

Find all intergers such that $2n^2+1$ divides $n^3+9n-17$.

Answer : $n=(2 \ and \  5)$

I did it.

As $2n^2+1$ divides $n^3+9n-17$, then $2n^2+1 \leq n^3+9n-17 \implies n \geq 2$

So $n =2$ is solution and doens't exist solution when n<2. How can I do now to find 5 ? Or better, how can you solve this with another good method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

If integer $d$ divides $n^3+9n-17,2n^2+1$

$d$ must divide  $2(n^3+9n-17)-n(2n^2+1)=17n-34$

$d$ must divide  $17(2n^2+1)-2n(17n-34)=68n+17$

$d$ must divide  $68n+17-4(17n-34)=153$

So the necessary condition is  $2n^2+1$ must divide $153$

$\implies2n^2+1\le153\iff n^2\le76\iff-9<n<9$

Comment: I was thinking it. As $n \geq 2 \implies 2 \leq n <9$.So now I have to test all of them ?

Comment: @Ewin, Welcome. We still need to test for $2\le n\le8$. I'm thinking of reducing that like $n\not\equiv\pm2\pmod5$ as $153\not\equiv0\pmod5$

Comment: @Ewin Worth emphasis: Lab is implicitly using the extended Euclidean algorithm to eliminate $\,n\,$ (or, equivaently, compute the Bezout identity for the gcd of the two expressions). This can also be done using modular arithmetic - see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The elimination in Lab's answer essentially employs the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute a Bezout identity. As usual, when we need only the result, such calculations can be simplified using modular arithmetic (so simple they can often be done *mentally* with practice). For example

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
2n^2+1\ &\,\mid &\, n^3+9n-17\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{#0c0}{2n^2}\!+\color{#c00}1\!:\ \ 0 &\equiv&\, 2\,(n^3+\ 9n\,-\,17)\\[.2em]
&\equiv&\, \color{#0a0}{2n^2}n + 18n -34\\[.2em]
&\equiv&\, 17(n\!-\!2)\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{2n^2}\equiv -\color{#c00}1\\[.2em]
2(\color{#90f}{n\!+\!2})\times{\rm prior}\,\Rightarrow\ \  0 &\equiv&\, 34(n\!-\!2)(\color{#90f}{n\!+\!2})\\[.1em] 
&\equiv&\, 17\cdot\color{#0a0}{2n^2}-34\cdot 4\equiv -153 
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

**Remark** $\ $ The multiplication by the factor $\,2(\color{#90f}{n\!+\!2})\,$ in the 2nd last step is not ad-hoc. Rather, it corresponds to taking the "norm" of a quadratic number, since here we have that $\, \color{#0a0}{n^2} \equiv -1/2\,$ so, ring-theoretically, $\,n\,$ behaves like $\,\sqrt{-1/2} = \sqrt{-2}/2,\,$ so we can do things like taking "norms" of expressions involving the "surd" $\,n,\,$ in order to get a [simpler multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242), by mapping "irrational" obects into "rational" objects - as I did above, viz. $\,0\equiv \alpha\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 2 N(\alpha) = 2\alpha\alpha'\equiv -153.$

We can also do the above computation using a [slight generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242) of the Euclidean algorithm that allows us to scale by integers coprime to the gcd.

The reason why this works will become clearer when one learns about various *universal* viewpoints of ring-theoretic objects. To me this is one of the most beautiful aspects of algebra - dramatically illustrating the success and power of the abstraction of algebraic structures such as rings.

Comment: I see it very nice ! +1 ;) Thanks

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887159/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/898713/242) for more examples using **norms**.

Answer (score 1):

hint: the quotient
$$\frac{n^3+9n-17}{2n^2+1}$$ can be written as $$n/2+1/2\,{\frac {17\,n-34}{2\,{n}^{2}+1}}$$