# Let $d=GCD(n^2+5,n^3-5n^2+6n)$ show that $d|630$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $d=GCD(n^2+5,n^3-5n^2+6n)$ show that $d|630$

My work: $d|n^3+5n,n^3-5n^2+6n\implies\ d|5n^2-n,5n^2+25\implies d|n+25 $
Now I can't go further!!

Comment: If $\ f(n) = n^2+5\ $ then $\,d\mid f(n),n\!+\!25\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid  {f(n)\ \rm mod}\ (n\!+\!25) = f(-25) = 630 \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Please explain more about this: $f(n) \mod (n+25)=f(-25)$

Comment: By Division $\, f(n) = q(n) (n - a) + r,\,$ so $\,f(a) = r = f(n)\ {\rm mod}\ n\!-\!a\ $ ([Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you so much:)

Comment: I added a link to Wikipedia. You could of course do the division if you were not aware of the remainder theorem, i.e. do the final step of the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,f(n) = n^2+5.\,$ Then $\,d\mid \color{#c00}{f(n),n\!+\!25}\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid  \overbrace{{f(n)\ \rm mod}\ (n\!+\!25) = f(-25)}^{\textstyle\!\! \color{#c00}{f(n)} - (\color{#c00}{n\!+\!25})q(n) = r(n)} = 630\, $ where we used the [Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) $\ f(n)\equiv f(a)\pmod{n-a}$

**Remark** $\ $ It is simpler to work modulo the common divisor $\,d,\,$ namely

$ n^2\!+5\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv -5}\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv n(\color{#c00}{n^2})\!-5\color{#c00}{n^2}\!+6n\equiv (\color{#c00}{-5})n-5(\color{#c00}{-5})+6n\equiv \color{#0a0}{n+25} $

thus $\ \color{#0a0}{n\equiv -25}\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv \color{#0a0}n^2+5\equiv (\color{#0a0}{-25})^2+5\equiv 630,\ $ therefore $\ d\mid 630$.

---

Alternatively $\, 25\!+\!n\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\ 0 \equiv (25 + n)\,(25 - n)\equiv 25^2\!-n^2\equiv 625-(-5)\equiv 630$

essentially $\,\ 25\!+\!\sqrt5\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv (25\!+\sqrt5)(25\!-\!\sqrt5)\equiv 625,\, $ like taking a norm in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt 5]$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074812/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/898713/242) for more examples using **norms**.